# Running GamingAnywhere from Shell scripting (startup) in ubuntu / Linux

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to run game on gamingAnywhere "Event-Driven Server" by shell scripting at startup. I tried lots of ways but not really working.

1.

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin -e './ga-server-event-driven config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf'
```

but it couldn't run the game.

2.

```
/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/ga-server-event-driven /Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf
```

It runs the game but doesn't runs all the modules e.g ga-hook-sdk.so

3.

I tried pipping too but didn't worked either.

I want to run the game with all modules. I hope the 1st method can help but child process exited with code 0. doesn't work.

I'm new to this shell scripting. So help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that
 normally (not at startup, but after you log on) the method 2 works for you

if my assumption is right then it must be some environment variable definition is missed or incomplete at startup. To figure that out, I suggest you to make a wrapper script around your application:

```
#!/bin/sh
env | sort >/tmp/gameenv
/Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/ga-server-event-driven /Path-to-gamingAnywhere/bin/config/server.assaultcube.linux.conf
```

Run this script manually first (when the game starts correct way) and save the content of /tmp/gameenv. Then put this script in your startup and compare the newer content of the /tmp/gameenv to the previous one. They will be for sure different, but you'll have to figure out yourself what part of the difference is relevant. 
My bet is that is LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but it can be more than that.